azure flexible server migration failing with collation UTF8
we're testing migration of postgres running on a VM to azure flexible server using the migration option in the portal.  On the validation it fails saying
Error 603401: Collation mismatch. Collation en_GB.UTF8 in database xxxxxx is not present on target server.
Flexible server has collation en_GB.utf8 (lowercase) in pg_collations but not en_GB.UTF8 (uppercase).  However, I can create a database with en_GB.UTF8.
Is UTF8 the same as utf8?  Should we abandon the migration option and just do a dump/restore into a database created with UTF8?

Can you check my answer and confirm if it works?

So this is a tricky one. In PostgreSQL, collation names are case-sensitive. This means that en_GB.UTF8 and en_GB.utf8 are considered DIFFERENT collations by PostgreSQL, as illogical as it may seem to a developer.
Here is a way to make sure your server has the appropriate collate:
SELECT * FROM pg_collation WHERE collname = 'en_GB.UTF8';

If the output is 0 roles - this collation does not exist, create it:
CREATE COLLATION "en_GB.UTF8" (provider = 'libc', locale = 'en_GB.UTF8');

You can then execute the first query again to confirm the creation. After this you can try to migrate again and see if that solves the problem.
I would strongly advocate against the use of dump and restore because it does bypass some set constraints in some cases. If you are not 100% familiar with the database and if you don't know how everything will be effected by this process, as well as how to reverse the effects back to the proper set, then you shouldn't do a dump and restore.

Thanks Dimitar.  I tried creating a new collation but the migration service still shows the same message, I wonder if it's because the collowner is not the azure superuser (which I can't connect as)
